# Spliced Distributions Framework for python

Tags: regression, python, nonlinear-regression, kurtosis

There is an article [Fat-Tailed Regression Modeling with Spliced
Distributions](https://www2.math.uconn.edu/%7Egan/ggpaper/gan2018spliced.pdf)
that describes fat-tailed regression modeling by fitting the distribution consisting of N components (different distributions) on exclusive argument intervals.

Is there a framework or common way to implement this modeling in python?